# django: mysterious padding of strings in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using the following template code to try to produce a list in the format 'a, b, c and d':

```
{% for item in list %}
  {% if not forloop.first %}
    {% if not forloop.last %}
      ,
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if forloop.last %}
    and
  {% endif %}
  {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

The actual output I'm getting is 'a , b , c and d' (note the spaces before the commas).

What's going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after several attempts I think I've found a solution, it's a bit verbose but it does what you want - no extra spaces -

```
{% for item in list %}
    {% if forloop.revcounter > 2 %}
        {{ item }},
    {% else %}
         {% if forloop.revcounter == 2 %}
              {{ item }} and
         {% else %}
              {{ item }}
         {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

`forloop.revcounter` is counting down from the end of the loop, so you add the 'and' to the second last item and leave the last one without anything.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the fact that I can lose the spaces in the rendered HTML but keep the whitespace in my template code though.

Comment: With a slight rearrangement, this was great. Just switch `{{ item }}` and `and` around in line 6.

Comment: Can you please correct for the benefit of anyone who stumbles on this in the future? :)

Comment: I'm getting my revcounter confused. forloop.revcounter == 1 is the last iteration - I wanted the second last. I've updated my code.

Comment: your switch will leave the comma after 'c' (which could have been achieved with just forloop.last). The code above replaces the comma on the second last iteration with ' and', leaving the last iteration to simple add the last item.

Answer (score 1):

Django inserts all the spaces that your template contains:

```
{% for item in list %}{% if not forloop.first %}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endif %}{% if forloop.last %} and {% endif %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}
```

---

By the way, your template renders the wrong output if the list contains only one value. The corrected template looks like:

```
{% for item in list %}
    {% if not forloop.first %}
        {% if forloop.last %}
            and
        {% else %}
            ,
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

And without the unwanted space it becomes:

```
{% for item in list %}{% if not forloop.first %}{% if forloop.last %} and {% else %}, {% endif %}{% endif %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: [spaceless documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#spaceless): Only space between tags is removed – not space between tags and text.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a simple [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

```
@register.filter
def format_list(li):
    """
    Return the list as a string in human readable format.

    >>> format_list([''])
    ''
    >>> format_list(['a'])
    'a'
    >>> format_list(['a', 'b'])
    'a and b'
    >>> format_list(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    'a, b and c'
    >>> format_list(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
    'a, b, c and d'
    """
    if not li:
        return ''
    elif len(li) == 1:
        return li[0]
    return '%s and %s' % (', '.join(li[:-1]), li[-1])
```

I'm far from an expert in python and there's probably a better way to do it. But still, this seems clean at the "django level", use it as such:

```
{{ your_list|format_list }}
```

What I like with this solution is that it is reusable, is more readable, has less code, and has tests.

Check out the documentation on [writing template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) for details on how to install it.

Also, you might notice that this function comes with doctests, refer to [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs) to learn how to run the tests.

Here's a way:

```
>>> python -m doctest form.py -v
Trying:
    format_list([''])
Expecting:
    ''
ok
Trying:
    format_list(['a'])
Expecting:
    'a'
ok
Trying:
    format_list(['a', 'b'])
Expecting:
    'a and b'
ok
Trying:
    format_list(['a', 'b', 'c'])
Expecting:
    'a, b and c'
ok
Trying:
    format_list(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
Expecting:
    'a, b, c and d'
ok
1 items had no tests:
    form
1 items passed all tests:
   5 tests in form.format_list
5 tests in 2 items.
5 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but for a single use case I'm going for a solution that doesn't a custom template filter.

Comment: You could also add this as a model method.